# Is there a way to escape a variable call in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, escaping

I am trying to use powershell to generate a build.include script for visual studio. They both use `${variable}` as a way of referencing variables.

I was wondering if there is a way to escape that in a string.

E.g

```
$string = @'
This is a `${string} I want to escape and {0} one I do not want to
'@ -f $Var
```

I looked online and it said to escape $ you have to use the backtick. Doesn't seem to work for variables though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You must put double brackets.

Example:

```
$string = @'
This is a ${{string}} I want to escape and {0} one I do not want to
'@ -f $Var
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the following syntax:

```
$Var = 'one'

$string = @"
This is a `$Var I want to escape and {0} I do not want to
"@ -f $Var

$string
```

Generates the following output:

```
This is a $Var I want to escape and one I do not want to
```

Another option is embedding the variable:

```
@"
This is a `${Var} I want to escape and $Var I do not want to
"@
```

Some remarks:

- A here string is always between double quotes `@""@`
- To escape a character use the backtick `

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually need it with the curly brackets as well though seemingly. Since that is how visual studio will read it. As in I need `${variable}` to actually display inside the string not the value of the variable

Comment: Updated answer  with the brackets.